# How to preserve bytesobjects in a dataframe column through HTTP server in python3?

Tags: python, pandas, http, byte, bytestream

I have a pandas dataframe. The 'data' column contains bytes bojects (binary files)

df = pd.DataFrame({'file_hash' : [01ccba93f3647ca50..., 739b24dc0dfea....],
'data' : [b'x\x9cd\xbbuT\x1c\xc1\xb7-\xdc\xf8 A\x12\xdc..., b'x\x9c\xcc\xbaeTT\xdf\x1b?z\x08\t\xa5A%$\x15a...]})

Now, I am sending this through a http server

```
bytes_obj = zlib.compress((output.to_csv(index=False)).encode())
self.wfile.write(bytes_obj)
```

While I am able to the dataframe at client side,

```
response = requests.get(url)
response_bytes = response.content
response_dataframe = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(zlib.decompress(response_bytes)))
```

The bytes object is now strings like `"b'x\x9cd\xbbuT\x1c\xc1\xb7-..."`. If I convert these strings, the become like `b'b\'x\\x9cd\\xbbuT\\x1c\\xc1\\xb7`

I tried many ways but just cannot get back the the exact bytes objects. I would really appreciate some suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It feels stupid but I think I should mention the solution as it can save someone's time.

I just used `ast.literal_eval` function from the `ast` module.

Basically, liternal_eval converts a string which looks like a bytes object to real bytesobject. So, string`"b'x\x9cd\xbbuT\x1c\xc1\xb7-..."`becomes bytes object b'x\x9cd\xbbuT\x1c\xc1\xb7-...

In my case,

```
response_dataframe["data"] = response_dataframe["data"].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
```

and not the data column containts the bytes objects I needed.